# Unable to move / delete rows in shared workbook - Not enough resources

Tags: vba, excel

this one's a bit of a painful one so thank you for your help and patience with me.

We have an Excel spreadsheet that  we use as a master file for our website products. As such there are quite a few sheets and quite a few products on each running along side some macros to provide some extra functionality (turning entered data into HTML for product page, etc).

My issue is that one of our most used spreadsheets has become a trouble in that it has some phantom formatting all the way down to the millionth-and-something row and all the way across, causing the last cell to be the very last cell possible.

The issue that has finally popped up as a result is that we can no longer move rows in, out or around the sheet (a required functionality) as it results in an 'out of resources error'.

I've tried:

- Highlight all rows below used range to right-click> delete - Results in runtime error (from macro)
- Highlighting large chunks of rows and using Clear All - Resulted in the 38MB file bloating to 380MB
- Deleting a chunk of rows at a time - Maxed out at 1,000 before it caused Excel to crash
- Moving to new spreadsheet - Broke all our macros (which I did not write and am not proficient enough to fix on a new sheet)
- Disabling macros and trying the above options, only marginally more efficient but still out of resources

I'm at my wits end on this one and, while we can continue with most day-to-day functions, we will soon be completely unable to use this particular sheet as we need it at all.

I'm wondering if there might be a way to run a VBA script to remove these rows, potentially one by one? I've tried running a short script that went something like rows[960,1000000].Delete (forgive my terrible VBA markup), but this also resulted in not enough resources errors.

I'm wondering if there's anything like:

```
row = 960;
while(row<=1048576){row.Delete};
```

Continuing, the runtime error debug points me to the below if statement within the macro:

```
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

Where Target is the variable passed to the sub.

Which strikes me as very odd because my (limited) understanding of VBA and IF's in general simply recognizes that 'if my selection is larger than 1 (row?), do not run this code..

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Please share the macro/file if it is not business confidential. Some of us must have faced this kind of issue. I have encountered similar but the ClearAll then Delete works.

Comment: I will try and identify if the code itself is okay to share, as I mentioned I'm not all too familiar with VBA, but I would be happy to share what I can.

Comment: If Target is a range then you need to use `Target.rows.count` Are you using code to delete rows? or is this a separate issue? Don't mix problems (start a new question for another issue) and please post your code if you have a question on it. We still don't know what kind of variable Target is.

Comment: I really don't think code is the best way to fix your worksheet. It can best be done manually as it should not be a recurring problem.

Comment: @D_Bester The `Target.Count` line is the code within the macro that causes the runtime error when selecting all the rows FOR deletion, not really a separate issue.

Comment: Can you add line `Debug.Print Target.Address` before that **If** line? This lets you know that Range of the Target just like "5:7".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method only if you don't have any links into or out of the sheet that will get broken. Also might have Sql connections that might get broken. Might need to disable macros. **There are many possible problems with this approach. Use at your own risk.**

1. Note the exact "Name" and "(Name)" of the sheet; Look in the VBA code window at the properties for the sheet. "Name" is the name displayed on the worksheet tab. "(Name)" is the code name visible only in the properties window.
2. Make a list of range names on the sheet.
3. Copy the data to a new sheet.
4. Copy any macros to the new sheet.
5. Delete the old sheet.
6. Rename the "Name" and "(Name)" of the new sheet the same as the old one.
7. Recreate range names.

A better method if you don't have too many formats:

1. Disable macros and set calculation to manual. This avoids recalculating while doing your delete operation.
2. Select entire sheet and clear formats.
3. Delete all rows below your data.
4. Redo your formatting. Select entire column (not just used area) to apply format if applicable.

It is important to remove formatting on the entire sheet from A1 to the end. Otherwise you'll get the bloat you mentioned. Just that step may solve your problem. If not then proceed with removing all the rows below the data. This should not cause file size bloat.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response (SO never ceases to amaze!).
To disable, I had Macro Security set to Disable with notification, is there a better way? I also ran a debug on the runtime error and will update my post with that.

Comment: Disable with notification is fine.

Comment: Thanks for that. Had to untrust it to renable the macro disabling. 
With your second suggestion, I was able to select everything, but still received a not enough resources error when trying to proceed with clear all. I was however able to delete more rows at once than previous (20k~ as opposed to 1k) which may be suffice, if not lots of work.

Comment: There's a big difference between "Clear All" (losing data) and "Clear Formats" (losing formats).

Comment: The first option has indeed worked for me. At first simply naming it the same names as the previous sheet didn't work, then I found that each sheet had a small sub script to call the macro itself. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: O! forgot to mention about worksheet objects, names and macros.